# Fetch dict data from array

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

```
{
"valueSet": true,
"valueList": [
    {},
    {
        "conId": "003q000000jvwIrAAI"
    }
],
"httpCode": 200,
"errorSet": false,
"errorList": []
}
```

This is the response, what I am getting from server. But actually I am new to swift, so I don't know how to get the value of that "conId". I am doing the below code to get valueList but after that how to get that, I am not getting how to get that "conId". I need to send that conId as string in callback.

```
let parseResult: [String : AnyObject]
                do{
                    parseResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print("\(parseResult)")
                } catch {
                    print("Could not parse data as Json \(String(describing: data))")
                    return
                }

                if let valueSet = parseResult["valueSet"] {
                    let value  =  valueSet as! Bool
                    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if let valueList = parseResult["valueList"] {
                        print(valueList)
                    if(httpResponse.statusCode == Constants.KNetworkSuccessCode) && (value == true) {
                        callback(httpResponse.statusCode, value, "")
                    }else {
                        callback(httpResponse.statusCode, value, "")
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should use Codable protocol if you are using Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of `conId` in following way...

```
//get the "valueList" from response
if let valueList = obj["valueList"] as? [[String: Any]] {

  //get the conId from [String: Any]
  for item in valueList {

    if let conId = item["conId"] as? String {
        print(conId)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here it is throwing error. "Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'".

Comment: The error is b'coz of `as! [String : AnyObject]` just change it to `parseResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : Any]`

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You need to cast valueList as an array of dictionaries like this:

```
if let valueList = parseResult["valueList"] as? [[String: String]] {
```

Then you can just loop over the valueList to find what you want, or directly access it with `valueList[1]["conId"]`.

Note, I use `as? [[String: String]]` to make sure valueList is returned as the correct data type, or else it will be nil and fail the `if let`. I would recommend using `as?` for your casts instead of `as!`, so you can catch errors that way.